# Cannot create new method overwritten CatalogController using DependencyRegistrar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods, dependency-injection, controller, nopcommerce

I'm facing this problem:

I want that a new method from a controller that we have in a new project added to the solution, to be called from a view.

More specifically, I want to override the original catallog controler, to mantein clean the main solution.

This is the structure of the new project.

[image: new project structure]

I'm using DependencyRegistrar this way, but it keeps going to the main controller.

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
    public void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder, NopConfig config)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<xxxxxCatalogController>().As<CatalogController>();
        builder.RegisterType<xxxxxService>().As<IxxxxxService>();

    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }


}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you calling controller methods directly from your view?

Comment: @Fran because it's the way they are called on nopcommerce views, for example  `@Html.Action("TopMenu", "Catalog")`

Comment: @amibumping: To override nopcommerce default controller method from your plugin, you'll need to use `RouteProvider` which inherited from `IRouteProvider`. Dependency register won't help you!!

Comment: @Div Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it. But if it helps it's not a plugin or a widget what I want to make, just create a new project associated to the solution, that's why I was using autofac's dependency injection.